# Spatial data extraction using Python

Tags: python, data-extraction, data-export

I have a lot of UK data and what I would like to do is extract this data based upon a post code, co-ordinates, grid ref etc.

Is this possible using Python?

Comment: Yes, it most certainly is.

Comment: Thanks @PiotrKamoda, care to expand a little?

Comment: Well it's difficult to say anything since we know nothing. It'd help this question to add specific information. F.e.: Where is the data located - [locally/REST Service/database/file/etc...]? Do you want to extract the data only localy, or do you have target database/file/report? Do you need ETL processes to EXTRACT-TRANSFORM-LOAD data or simply need to GUI the data? Because you know, Python is a programming language and it's options are night limitless, but for some things there are better solutions, as with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you just have the postcodes, you'll first most likely need to convert them to coordinates. This can be done with 3rd party tools such as [Googles Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/), or the Royal Mail UK Postcode mailing list. Once you have coordinates, with this, you can plot them however you like using other tools such as [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), or make your own.

Comment: Thank you Slopax. I actually have the both the post codes and the co-ordinates. At the moment, we send all this data to a separate business line who, on request, send us it over in a more user friendly excel "report" based on provided drive time/location. They charge us an annual fee for this service, ultimately, that's what I am trying to get rid of!